# La herramienta "Siguiente medalla de etiqueta" no se actualiza automaticamente

Tags: bug, estado-completado, perfil

Me percate de lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la sección "Siguiente medalla de etiqueta", el numero de votos no se actualiza diariamente como si sucede con la etiqueta en la sección etiquetas. Por el contrario hay que actualizarlo a mano.

Si tocas la ruedita de la izquierda, en el menú que se despliega aparecen los valores reales (79 en este caso) y al volver a seleccionar la etiqueta y aceptar, la pagina del perfil queda actualizada.

NOTA: Se que el 22 vs el 19 están bien por que el 22 incluye las preguntas y el 19 no. Pero el 79 solo tiene en cuenta los votos en respuestas y ese es por cierto el numero que se ve ahora que ya lo actualice manualmente.

No entiendo para que sirve la herramienta de "seguimiento" si no lleva a cabo ningún seguimiento... ;)

Creo que esto debería actualizarse automáticamente sin necesidad de intervenir de forma manual.

Comment: no está funcionando bien, a mi solo me deja elegir Java y tengo respuestas en varias etiquetas.

Comment: A mi me sale Java y JavaScript, me debería salir Python

Comment: quizá hay una lista, yo tengo solo las mismas 2.

Comment: Que aparezcan sólo unas cuantas etiquetas se podría considerar el comportamiento esperado. No todas las etiquetas cumplen los requisitos para dar medalla ([ver respuesta relacionada con explicación](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/447/250)) y no tendría sentido dejar elegir una etiqueta de la que aún no se puede obtener medalla.

Comment: esto esta resuelto ...

Comment: Dejaré el flag todavía para que un dev u otro moderador con más poderes pueda brindar una explicación/respuesta a este tema.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/